# Kafka Streams Application consumer offset getting reset to Earliest on restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka Streams application that is experiencing weird behavior. Randomly when the job is killed and restarted, the consumer group is getting its offsets reset to earliest and all the old records are getting reprocessed.

Is there anything specific that needs to be done and we're missing that?

```
"buffered.records.per.partition": 512000, 
"cache.max.bytes.buffering": 134217728, 
"commit.interval.ms": 30000, 
"retries": 2147483647, 
"acks": "all", 
"processing.guarantee": "exactly_once", 
"compression.type": "snappy", 
"auto.offset.reset": "latest"
```

Comment: can you show the config properties

Comment: Is the consumer group the same value between restarts?

Comment: @Deadpool below is our configuration:       
        `"buffered.records.per.partition": 512000,
        "cache.max.bytes.buffering": 134217728,
        "commit.interval.ms": 30000,
        "retries": 2147483647,
        "acks": "all",
        "processing.guarantee": "exactly_once",
        "compression.type": "snappy",
        "auto.offset.reset": "latest"`

Comment: @maitreyak yes, the consumer group is not changed.

Comment: Your configuration looks good with "auto.offset.reset":"latest"

Comment: Can you double check if offsets are committed successfully via `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh`? Also, just to double check: do don't change the `application.id` configuration on restart? Last, you code does not overwrite `auto.offset.reset` from the config?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thanks for the response. The problem is when that happens, the __consumer_offsets topic gets updated with older offsets. The application.id remains same. our code does commit manually and auto.offset.reset=latest (no overwriting to earliest).

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow. "when that happens" -> do you mean when the job is killed in restarted? "get updated with older offsets" -> how/why? "our code does commit manually" -> Kafka Streams does not really allow manual commits. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, yes. Please see below explanation. Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier.
When our Kafka Streams job is killed and restarted, we're seeing that the offsets for that particular consumer group got reset to "earliest" available even though we're not specifying anywhere that it should. how/why - we don't know, unfortunately! :(

About the manual offset commit, my bad, I got that confused. Yes, streams doesn't allow for manual commits.

Comment: Can you check of offset are committed via `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool? Also check the log files if there are WARN logs that committing failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have set `"auto.offset.reset": "latest"`, so clearly that property isn't getting applied.

> To guarantee at-least-once processing semantics and turn off auto commits, Kafka Streams overrides `enable.auto.commit` consumer config value to `false`. Consumers will only commit explicitly via `commitSync` calls when the Kafka Streams library or **a user decides to commit the current processing state**

- [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#enable-auto-commit)

Therefore, it seems you have not performed a terminal action on any stream item such that it would make a synced commit.